# Delphi missing Brh_Telapi_Tlb.dcu

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

While compiling Delphi application there is an error

**[Fatal Error] UnitModuleU.pas(9): File not found: 'Brh_Telapi_TLB.dcu'**

I checked in my system but i cannot able find any .dcu file or .pas file related to it.Is there any solution how to rectify this error.I am using Baraha software ,as this error is anything related to this software?

Answer (score 2):

`Brh_Telapi_TLB` is not one of the standard Delphi units, so it has to come from a third-party component you're using. Given the starting `Brh`, it would seem probable that it's one of the `Baraha` files. You'll need to track down a copy of that file from reinstalling the software, or contact the software vendor to get one.

Answer (score 2):

brh_Telapi is the name of the ActiveX control.
If you have the software installed on your development environment then import the Baraha  activeX control via "import activeX control" option. The Brh_Telapi_TLB.pas will be automatically be generated.

Comment: There is no such file related to the name Baraha activeX, you have any idea where this file is located.

Comment: If you have installed the Baraha software, chances are great that a COM componenent (ActiveX) has been installed. Just do "import activeX control" from the menu and see if you can find a Baraha related component

Answer (score 0):

`UnitModuleU.pas` file calling a function from **compiled unit file** `'Brh_Telapi_TLB.dcu'`. It is not possible to compile that project without this file. You should put this file one of your library paths.